# how to plot using ggplot2 package in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to use `ggplot2` package to plot a dataframe in r. The dataframe `df` has multiple columns, saying date, col1, col2, col3, etc. I use the following code to plot, no error messages are reported, but no plot comes out. I tried `show(p)`, it doesn't work either. Can anyone tell what's the issue here. Thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <-
  ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(Date,col1)) +
  geom_line(aes(Date,col2), col='red') + 
  labs(y="cost", title="PLOT")
print(p)
```

Here is the data I use.

```
         Date     col1   col2  col3
1 2011-01-01   718.8011  100   861.9
2 2011-01-02   777.9102  100   861.9
3 2011-01-03   856.4745  100   861.9
4 2011-01-04   626.4703  100   861.9
```

**dput**

```
structure(list(Date = c("2011-01-01", "2011-01-02", "2011-01-03", 
"2011-01-04"), col1 = c(718.8011, 777.9102, 856.4745, 626.4703
), col2 = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), col3 = c(861.9, 861.9, 861.9, 
861.9)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Better to make a reproducible example with example of the df data-frame.

Comment: Thanks. I added the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work you need to cast you Date to factors or Dates

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- structure(list(Date = c("2011-01-01", "2011-01-02", "2011-01-03", 
                                      "2011-01-04"), col1 = c(718.8011, 777.9102, 856.4745, 626.4703
                                      ), col2 = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), col3 = c(861.9, 861.9, 861.9, 
                                                                                    861.9)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df_example %>%
  mutate(Date = Date %>% ymd) %>% 
  pivot_longer(col1:col3) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = Date,y = value,color = name) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help. I use exactly the same code, but no figure comes out. Can you think of what's the issue?

Comment: Others shared the code with me and the figure was output to other place. Your code can solve my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the format of the data that it should be long format instead of wide format, here is how you can solve this using tidyr package;

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <-
  data.frame(
    Date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01", "2011-01-02", "2011-01-03", "2011-01-04")),
    col1 = c(718.8011, 777.9102, 856.4745, 626.4703),
    col2 = c(100, 100, 100, 100),
    col3 = c(861.9, 861.9, 861.9, 861.9)
  )

df %>%
  gather(key = "Col", value = "value", -Date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, value, colour = Col)) +
  geom_line() + 
  labs(y = "cost", title = "PLOT")
```

[image]

Comment: Try `tidyr::pivot_longer` instead of `tidyr::gather` - more powerful and better named arguments

Comment: Thanks Nareman. I tried the same code as you post here. But no figure comes out, the same as I tried Bruno's code. Not sure what's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nareman. It turned out that the figure was output to other place. Your code can solve my problem.